# passing # symbol to params hash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postman, hashtag

I am handling some hashtag processing in a rails application.

Say us that I have programmed an endpoint which receives through `params` hash a string containing some hashtags. Some like that

`This string contains this #hashtag and this #one`.

I am using postman for testing my endpoints.

Now, when in postman I perform some like this:

`{{url}}/add?content=content=This string contains this #hashtag and this #one`

I receive in the `params` the string `"content"=>"This string contains this "`. That is, from the first occurrence of symbol `#` the remaining string is cut.

Very aware that my question is some naive, I dare to ask why that? What have I done wrong? and how could I manage for passing strings containing the `#` symbol?

Comment: Nice example of why it is error prone to generate URLs with string concatenation or interpolation instead of using a proper URI builder.

Comment: You have `content=` twice in you request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure [you encode](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html) whatever you are sending over in param.

```
URI.encode("This string contains this #hashtag and this #one")

#=> This%20string%20contains%20this%20%23hashtag%20and%20this%20%23one
```

Comment: With gratitude, I upvote and accept your answer. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Update your postman request to replace the `#` with `%23`

```
{{url}}/add?content=This string contains this %23hashtag and this %23one
```

In the future when doing something like this you can select a part of the params(or the whole thing) and right click and select `EncodeURIComponent`, as explained [here](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests/#url)